# JOptionPane via constructor not showing/prompting

Tags: java, swing, visibility, joptionpane

I am writing a script which will call a bunch of other scripts, passing proper parameters when necessary.  Since multiple scripts are being called, multiple points of failure are possible.  If a script fails halfway through the flow, it is logged and the user will be prompted to resume from that position when the program next starts.

Both a server and a user have the ability to start the program.  One is autonomous, one is not.  In the case of autonomy, I want the prompt to resume to have a 10 second timeout so if no input is received, the script will just start at the beginning.

I have moved from the static showOptionDialog to a JOptionPane constructed dialog so I can access it programmatically to kill it after 10 seconds.  **My issue is with the constructor, no prompt will occur.**

What I have tried:

- I have verified the code is entering the code block via the debug
  Log() script below.
- As you can see, I have tried adding a JFrame
  constructor.  The JFrame constructor, .add(), and
  frame.SetVisible(true) are new additions that have yielded no prompt
  as well.
- I have also commented out the 10 second
  dialog.setVisible(false) just in case it was getting called
  prematurely.

I am sure I'm missing something obvious, but I can't see it.

```
    if(foundErroredScript != null)
        {
            Log("debug - Found errored script, \"" + foundErroredScript + "\"");

            //Resume prompt
            Object[] options = {"Yes, resume", "No, start over"};               
            JFrame frame = new JFrame();
            JOptionPane pane = new JOptionPane("Would you like to resume from \"" + foundErroredScript + "\", AKA the last run script which errored?",
                    JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION,
                    JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE,
                    null,
                    options);
            frame.add(pane);
            final JDialog dialog = pane.createDialog("Found last errored module");
            Timer timer = new Timer(10000, new ActionListener()
            {
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
                {
                    //dialog.setVisible(false);
                }
            });
            timer.setRepeats(false);
            timer.start();

            frame.setVisible(true);
            dialog.setVisible(true);


            Log("User selected " + pane.getValue());
```

Comment: code in similair form works without issue, debug or post an SSCCE/MCVE short, runnable, compilable demonstrated bunch of words

Comment: untill JOptionPane is visible nothing will be happends, modal dialog to block (all) repaint(s) to already visible GUI

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out.

After following mKorbel's advice to simplify and isolate, I moved the JOptionPane to its own simple class.  I accidentally flipped the MessageType and OptionType.  The program threw an exception when isolated, but doesn't when running inside the main program.  This happens because the main program logic, which branches out from a class constructor, is originally called from the Main method which throws IOException.

So instead of this,

```
    JOptionPane pane = new JOptionPane("Would you like to resume from \"here\", AKA the last run script which errored?",
            JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION,
            JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE,
            null,
            options);
```

it should be this,

```
    JOptionPane pane = new JOptionPane("Would you like to resume from \"here\", AKA the last run script which errored?",
            JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE,
            JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION,
            null,
            options);
```

Silly mistake.

EDIT: I also removed the frame, as it was unnecessary for a primarily GUI-less application.

Comment: See also [*Using Headless Mode in the Java SE Platform*](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/javase/headless-136834.html).